# Child business rule is not firing in JBPM integration with Drools

Tags: jbpm, drools-guvnor, drools-flow

Let say I've parent and child workflow respectively p1 and c1.

JBPM looks like this:

> P1---->[script node]--->[business rule]--->[service node]----->[reusable-subprocess calling c1]
>
> C1---->[script node]---->[business rule node]----->[script]

Flow is stucking at `c1--->` business rule node. I have no Idea why it is stucking there. If I remove business rule in c1 it is working.

Here I'm using JBPM 5.5.0, and this is my c1--->business rule

```
dielact "mvel"
rule "rule2"
when
eval(true);
then
System.out.println("rule2::::::");
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you copy-paste the actual rule from your JBPM here? Because there is typo with the word "dielact", it should be "dialect".

Comment: No didn't copy paste

Comment: It is working now, bcoz I'm using statefull kbase, whenever I re-create ksession I need to call fireallrules I missed that.